# MySQL - Count across tables

Tags: mysql, count

I am trying to perform a count across multiple, linked tables:

```
select 
    vpp.Name
    ,count(sx.Occurences) as sx_Occurences
    ,count(vpp.Occurences) as vpp_Occurences
    ,count(sd.Occurences) as sd_Occurences
from v_p vpp
  left outer join s_x sx on sx.ID = vpp.ID
  left outer join s_d sd on sd.ID = vpp.ID 
  group by vpp.Name
```

This however gives me incorrect results (doing a count on one table only works fine, but as soon as I add a second (or a third, fourth...) the numbers are wrong.

Comment: Could it be that you have s_x or s_d occurrences that are not in v_p?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for this:

```
SELECT vpp.Name,
       (SELECT count(sx.Occurences) FROM s_x WHERE s_x.ID = vpp.ID) as sx_Occurences, 
       count(vpp.Occurences) as vpp_Occurences,
       (SELECT count(sd.Occurences) FROM s_d WHERE s_d.ID = vpp.ID) as sd_Occurences
  FROM v_p vpp
 GROUP BY vpp.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have 1:n relationship between at least 2 of the 3 tables. In the resultset you will have more records than you would have if you counted the records by each table individually.

If you want to count the distinct values of the given fields, then use count(distinct ...):

```
select 
    vpp.Name
    ,count(distinct sx.Occurences) as sx_Occurences
    ,count(distinct vpp.Occurences) as vpp_Occurences
    ,count(distinct sd.Occurences) as sd_Occurences
from v_p vpp
  left outer join s_x sx on sx.ID = vpp.ID
  left outer join s_d sd on sd.ID = vpp.ID 
  group by vpp.Name
```

Otherwise, you need to do the counting individually by each table. You can combine the 3 queries as subqueries:

```
select 
    t1.Name
    ,sx_Occurences
    ,vpp_Occurences
    ,sd_Occurences
from 
  (select name, id, count(vpp.Occurences) as vpp_Occurences
   from v_p vpp
   group by name, id) t1
  left outer join 
  (select id, count(sx.Occurences) as sx_Occurences
   from s_x sx
   group by id) t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
  left outer join
  (select id, count(sd.Occurences) as sd_Occurences
   from s_d sd
   group by id) t3 on t1.ID = t3.ID
```